# summarize data in group by in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm not sure what should I write in the following SQL query to show the following result:

Data:
[image]

Color is unique column...

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select color as [name/color], value
from your_table
union all
select name, sum(value)
from your_table
group by name
```

And if you need a specific order then you can do

```
select [name/color], value 
from 
(
    select color as [name/color], value, name as order_column
    from your_table
    union all
    select name, sum(value), name
    from your_table
    group by name
) x 
order by order_column
```

Comment: You have to be more specific if that query is not what you want.

Comment: when i execute your query John and David rows go to end